# Autofill textbox based on input in another

Tags: vb.net, data-binding, autocomplete, textbox

I have a page where users can insert new records to a table. Namely, there is a field named PartNum that appears twice and they occur in separate TemplateFields in a DetailsView.

I want the second occurence to automatically fill as the user types into the first one. So far I have the code behind for the first as:

```
Protected Sub PartNumChange(ByVal sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs)
    Dim str As String
    str = Me.ToString()
    Try
        DetailsView1A.DataItem("PrimaryKey5") = str
    Catch nre As NullReferenceException
    End Try

End Sub
```

Where str refers to the first textbox to grab the value in and "PrimaryKey5" is the one that should update as the user types.

Unfortunately, nothing seems to be happening at all. I do have AutoPostBack on. Do I need some kind of code-behind for the second textbox as well?

Answer (score 0):

Though you've not specified, your mention of Postback suggests that this is a web application not a client app.  The code you're writing is server-side, which means that it's not running in the user's browser and will only have a chance to run when the page is submitted to the server (e.g. if a button is clicked or a link navigated) - even with AutoPostBack you're not going to get a refresh for every keypress.  Although it's *possible* to post back for every keypress in a textbox, that will cause your page to refresh repeatedly and isn't going to be a nice user experience.

More likely, if you want this effect in a browser, you want to implement it as a client-side bit of Javascript.  The script can run in the client's browser without hitting the server and will give a much nicer experience.

Comment: Thanks, that's a really insightful answer.
But lets say now that I only want the second one to update when the first loses focus (like I click away from it). This code still doesn't seem to work then. Any ideas there? Thanks again!